# OnNewIntent in API 19 Android

Tags: android, onnewintent

I would like to recover the android intent my activity is launched with.

My activity, tested in API 19 (KitKat), besides the main intent, has the following intent filter and parameters:

```
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="false"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.svg" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But when I open a SVG file while the activity was running, it does not handle the new intent.
I tried the following combinations, launched the activity,

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"

android:launchMode="standard"

android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

combined with the following parameter, that makes 6 configurations

```
android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" or "false"
```

But none of them make the `onNewIntent` function to be called when I open a SVG with my application. Instead, it displays the previous state (onPause and onResume are called as expected, and onCreate is called instead).

The only workaround I found was to cal the `finish()` function from withing the `onPause()` method, so that it effectively terminates the application. I don't understand what is going on because it was working last year before I changed targets.

**What is the required configuration to access the calling intents each time?**

Related questions without answers to mine:

- [This blog](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode) explains that I should use "singleTop" but it is not working in my case.
- [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17546819/1287856) does not have any answer.
- [This famous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711785/1287856) describes the set-up of the intent. But in my case, I do not create the intent myself, android does.

Comment: did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment, my program works well and loads SVG as I wanted. Some points about my configuration (maybe it can help)

- I am targeting Android API 15. I gave up with the 19.
- I use `android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`
- I do not call `finish()` in the `onPause()` method
- `OnNewIntent` is never called, but the `onCreate` method is called which parse the new intent.
- The content of the activity manifest is the following:

  ```
  <activity
    android:name="com.example.mypackage"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="false"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="file" />
      <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
      <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.svg" />
      <data android:host="*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  ```