# Device Specific: onNewIntent() is not being called in Samsung Galaxy S4 - Android KitKat 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-intent, onnewintent

Before asking this question, I did a lot of search. But none of the answers here did work for me:
[onNewIntent is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446120/onnewintent-is-not-called),
[onNewIntent not called on restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594438/onnewintent-not-called-on-restart),
[onNewIntent() not getting called in some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546819/onnewintent-not-getting-called-in-some-devices),
[my onNewIntent is not calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209528/my-onnewintent-is-not-calling)

I am working on `NotificationManager` where my requirement is to open an `Activity` on tap of notification with values received through that notification.
I have tried the following piece of code while setting intent:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

I also set `launchMode` as `singleTop` in `Manifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="www.google.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

**The issue seems to be device specific**. I tried the same piece of code on `Nexus 7` and `onNewIntent` is being called there. But **somehow it is not working on Galaxy S4**.

**Questions:**

1. Have you guys faced similar problem in the past?
2. How do I fix it?
3. My biggest curiosity lies on "How can an API be device specific?"
4. Can I rely on `onNewIntent` API or should I look for an alternative? As observed, it seems like this issue doesn't repro on all devices. And I cannot test on all devices for its reliability.

Comment: Is `MyActivity` active (not finished) and in the task's back stack already when the notification is opened? Are you absolutely sure?

Comment: If `MyActivity` is not in the back stack, Android will create an instance of `MyActivity` and call `onCreate()`, but it **will not** call `onNewIntent()`. That's why it matters ;-)

Comment: I got your point. But how is it that the same scenario works in Nexus 7 and fails in S4? Ah, is it due to fragmentation?

Comment: I'm not sure yet. I'm trying to gather information at this stage. If I knew the answer to your question I would have already told you.

Comment: As of now I have figured out some alternative solution, a middle man `Activity` serves the purpose. But, I would appreciate if you find something and share with me.

Comment: Please explain how you've worked around this. I'm curious.

Comment: My problem was that I wanted to pass some data to a `LauncherActivity` on click of a notification. `onNewIntent` was such API where I was setting the new Intent and starting `LauncherActivity`. Since, onNewIntent was not getting called, `LauncherActivity` was being started with default intent and not with the intent it should. I got rid of `onNewIntent` completely by introducing a `MiddleActivity` and setting this activity to launch on click of notification. From this `Activity`, I launched the desired `LauncherActivity` by getting and setting correct `Intent`